# Different result about classic asp for query string

Tags: asp-classic

I am new in classic asp.

I added this two line on the top of document

```
<%@ Language=VBScript CODEPAGE=950 %>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=big5" />
```

And I written some simple code

```vb
Dim str0 
str0 = Request.ServerVariables("QUERY_STRING")
Response.write("Orginal string :"&str0)
```

And the query string contain the Chinese

```
http://www.mytest.com/test.asp?as=更
```

The output of different browser

Chrome:

```
Orginal string :as=%E6%9B%B4
```

IE:

```
Orginal string :as=更
```

May I know how can I solve this problem? Thanks

Comment: What happens if you specify `Response.Codepage = 950` before sending the response?

Comment: Also don't use `<meta>` tag to set `charset=big5` because this will instantly write back to the browser which disables certain actions server-side. Instead use `Response.Charset = "big5"` instead this does the same thing without the side effect.

Comment: Thanks for reply. But it cannot fix the problem.

Comment: Why are you using `Request.ServerVariables("QUERY_STRING")`? Try using `Request.QueryString` instead as that should automatically decode the querystring regardless of how the browser sends it.